# How to retrieve the value of the header column of a clicked cell?

Tags: jquery, html-table, click

I want the action does not happen when the click is performed in the column 'no action' and whatever the clicked cell.

```
<table id="table" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>heading 1</th>        
            <th>heading 2</th>
            <th>no action</th>
            <th>heading 4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[1]" /></td>
            <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 3</td>
            <td>row 1, cell 4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[2]" /></td>
            <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
            <td>row 2, cell 3</td>
            <td>row 2, cell 4</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


$('#table tbody tr').click(function(event) {
    var th = $('#table th').eq($(this).index());
    if(th.text() != 'no action'){
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$('#table tbody td').click(function (event) {
    var th = $('#users-table th').eq($(this).index());
    if (th.text() != 'no action') {
        if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
            $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', function (i, checked) {
                return !checked;
            })
        }
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/58yNj/)

---

But you can use event delegation model to skip the click event in the 3rd columnd

```
$('#table tbody').on('click', 'td:not(:nth-child(3))', function (event) {
    if (event.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        $(this).closest('tr').find(':checkbox').prop('checked', function (i, checked) {
            return !checked;
        })
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/LYTCe/)